# T-SQL Merge statement in stored procedure throws error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Recently I have had to change a query from the following (fully working):

```
/****** WORKING ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [operations].[ROIWarehouseDatas]
    (@Operation VARCHAR(50)    = NULL,
     @TableName NVARCHAR(255)  = NULL,
     @Results [dbo].[ForeSightData] READONLY) 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @err INT
    SET @err = 0

    IF (@Operation = 'Insert')
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(4000)
        DECLARE @ParamDefinition NVARCHAR(4000)

        SET @SQLString = N'TRUNCATE TABLE ['+ @TableName + N'];
                           INSERT INTO ['+ @TableName + N']
                               SELECT [ID], [BrandName], [AdvertName], [VersionName], [WCPM]
                               FROM @Results;';

        SET @ParamDefinition = N'@Operation VARCHAR(50), @Results [dbo].[ForeSightData] READONLY';

        EXECUTE sp_executesql  @SQLString, @ParamDefinition, @TableName, @Results
    END
    --ENDIF Insert

    SET @err = @@ERROR
    RETURN @err
END
```

To the following (not working):

```
/****** NOT WORKING ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [operations].[ROIWarehouseDatas]
    (@Operation VARCHAR(50)    = NULL,
     @TableName NVARCHAR(255)  = NULL,
     @Results [dbo].[ForeSightData] READONLY) 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @err INT
    DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(4000)
    DECLARE @ParamDefinition NVARCHAR(4000)

    SET @err = 0

    IF (@Operation = 'Insert')
    BEGIN
        SET @SQLString = N'MERGE INTO ['+ @TableName +'] AS T
                           USING @Results AS S ON T.ID = S.ID
                           WHEN MATCHED 
                               THEN UPDATE 
                                    SET T.[BrandName] = S.[BrandName],
                                        T.[AdvertName] = S.[AdvertName],
                                        T.[VersionName] = S.[VersionName],
                                        T.[VersionDuration] = S.[VersionDuration],
                                        T.[WCPM] = S.[WCPM]
                           WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
                               THEN INSERT ([ID], [BrandName], [AdvertName], [VersionName], [WCPM])
                                    VALUES (S.[ID], S.[BrandName], S.[AdvertName], S.[VersionName], S.[WCPM]);';
        SET @ParamDefinition = N'@Operation VARCHAR(50), @Results [dbo].[ForeSightData] READONLY';

        EXECUTE sp_executesql  @SQLString, @ParamDefinition, @TableName, @Results
    END
    --ENDIF Insert

    SET @err = @@ERROR
    RETURN @err
END
```

However, when I run the program I get the following error:

> An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name. Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''.
>   Incorrect syntax near ''.

I tried checking the syntax - and that came up as fine.

Comment: The first tip to debugging dynamic SQL is to print the sql string and then debug that as native SQL. e.g. before `EXECUTE sp_executesql ` add a line `print(@SQLString)`

Comment: Tip: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems not correct syntax for SQL **MERGE**.

`WHEN NOT MATCHED BY T THEN` should be `Target` not **T**:

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target 
   THEN .....
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it was an issue, definitely, however I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you share your UDT script?

Comment: The [dbo].[ForeSightData], is unfortunately not an actual table in the DB. It only apears in the stored proc as you see. It has the same definition of the table I am inserting it into. Here is the script for it:

Comment: ` SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 GO

 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
 GO

 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
  [ID] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
  [BrandName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
  [AdvertName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
  [VersionName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
  [WCPM] [float] NULL
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
 GO`

Comment: @CornelisdeJager, what's the value of `@Results`?

Comment: @CornelisdeJager, the only parameter in your query is the TVP, Remove `@TableName` from `sp_executesql` since that's used to build the query string and is not a parameter inside the query.

Comment: As an Update - @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ you were correct - that did solve the issue, the following issues I had was a result as SQL Injection and Mismatched formats.